# SELECT FROM one TABLE, COUNT FROM ANOTHER TABLE, WHRER

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have 2 tables. I write a query

```
SELECT REGION
        , COUNT (*) 
FROM CF_TT_CREATE CRT 
WHERE SUBSTR(CRT.TICKETNO,8,4) = 2020
GROUP BY REGION
ORDER BY COUNT(*);
```

The result of the query is:

```
| REGION | COUNT  |
+--------+--------+
|   R1   |    1   |
|   R7   |    1   |
|   R5   |   23   |
```

But I want the result of my query to be equal to

```
| REGION | COUNT  |
+--------+--------+
|   R2   |    0   |
|   R3   |    0   |
|   R4   |    0   |
|   R6   |    0   |
|   R8   |    0   |
|   R9   |    0   |
|   R10  |    0   |
|   R1   |    1   |
|   R7   |    1   |
|   R5   |   23   |
```

I have another table that has the name C_region and has some columns, one column is NAME and has R1, R2, . . . R10.

How I can obtain that result?

Comment: Are all the region names in `C_region` distinct? If they are, you need to left-outer-join that table to the result of your query, so that all the regions appear in the output.

Comment: Your post might be improved if you posted your data structure, probably as a [table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post).

Comment: Tip: If you use regular integer data type for the regions, life will become easier. Trust me.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use conditional count like so:

```
SELECT  C_region.Name
     , COUNT (case when SUBSTR(CRT.TICKETNO,8,4) = 2020 then 1 end) 
FROM C_region C
left join CF_TT_CREATE CRT  on CRT.REGION_ID = C.REGION_ID
GROUP BY C_region.Name
ORDER BY COUNT(*);
```

Comment: This will be very inefficient, since `GROUP BY` will apply to all the input rows (not filtered by the `SUBSTR` condition), and the number of groups will be the number of all regions, not just those that actually have rows that satisfy the `SUBSTR` condition. The query should be written so that the aggregation applies to, say, 10,000 rows out of 800,000 total rows, whenever possible, and assigned to three groups, not 15. While the optimizer may change the order between `group by` and `join`, it does not look at your `case` expression to apply the filter early.

Comment: Right. We agree on the assignment. My comment was about the approach taken, not the desired result. You can discard all the un-needed rows first (put that in a `where` clause somewhere, as the OP was trying to do); then count, and then use an outer join to add the "missing regions" to the output as the last step, not the first step.

Answer (score 0):

You may use below query -

```
SELECT CR.NAME
      ,COUNT (*) 
  FROM C_region CR
  LEFT JOIN CF_TT_CREATE CRT ON CR.NAME = CRT.REGION
                            AND SUBSTR(CRT.TICKETNO,8,4) = 2020
 GROUP BY CR.NAME
 ORDER BY COUNT(*);
```

Comment: The `WHERE` condition would make the outer join pointless

Comment: You could move the `where` condition to the `on` condition. But the more efficient solution is to do the aggregation first and only then do the join. Perhaps the optimizer will make that change for you anyway, but why not write it efficiently from the outset?

Comment: @DaveCosta & mathguy, make the suggested edit.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient solution is to filter by the `substr` condition first, so there are as few rows to aggregate as possible. Then aggregate, and the last step is to perform a left outer join. (Aggregate and only then join, so that there are as few rows to aggregate as possible; aggregation is the most expensive step in this query.)

```
select t.name as region, nvl(q.ct, 0) as ct
from   c_region t 
    left outer join
       (
         select region, count (*) as ct 
         from   cf_tt_create crt 
         where  substr(crt.ticketno,8,4) = 2020
         group  by region
       ) q
    on t.name = q.region
order  by ct;   --  or   order by ct desc   ?
```